# NGINX - 403 forbidden - Cannot serve static file from directory as root user

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403, centos7

Running Centos7. I'm having a problem serving a static html file from a subdirectory.  I've set all permissions to root and have set the user to root in the nginx.conf file. I've included my the config file and listing of the permissions for the directory that I'm trying to serve the html file from. The path and file I'm trying to serve from is /home/colin/

**NGINX.CONF**

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]   "$request" ' '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ''"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;
# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root /home/colin;
    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location /cap {
        autoindex on;
        try_files test.html /test.html;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

**PERMISSIONS**

```
f: /home/colin/test.html
drwxrwxrwx root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxr-xr-x root root colin
-rwxr-xr-x root root test.html
```

I've tried multiple configurations with different permission settings, using aliases and different subdirectories with same root permission - and the same problem occurs: 403 Forbidden. Am I missing something obvious here? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does `localhost/test.html` work?

Comment: @uzsolt nope, curl localhost/cap and curl localhost/test.html both return 403

Comment: Uhm, and what is `/cap`? Do you want `/home/colins/cap/test.html`?

Comment: @uzsolt yes that's correct. Hitting the url http://192.XX.XX.X/cap should direct me to /home/colin/cap/test.html

Comment: And do you have `cap` directory? :)

Comment: @uzsolt Yep, cap directory is in there. Sorry forgot to include that in my permission list

Comment: And what about `test.html`'s permission?